# How does convex splitting method work?

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, mathematics, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

I'm an undergraduate physics student and I'm simulating some partial differential equations using finite element method. For non-linear equations I found a method called linear convex splitting however I'm not sure how it works. From what I understand for now, I start with a non-linear equation
$$\dot u=−\frac{\partial F(u)} {\partial u}$$
where $F(u)$ is a free energy functional. Now $F(u)$ can be split into two convex functionals (one is contractive "c" and the other expansive "e") :
$$F(u)=F_c(u)−F_e(u)$$
so that the equation can be written as:
$$\frac{u^{k+1}-u^k} {dt} =\frac{\partial  F_c(u^{k+1})} {\partial u} - \frac{\partial F_e(u^{k})} {\partial u}$$
Variatial derivative of $F_c$ would then end up having only linear terms and derivative of $F_e$ non-linear or both linear and non-linear which would be perfect for solving non-linear equations. One example I found was:
$$F(u)=\frac{1}{4} (u^2−1)^2$$
and it was split into:
$$F_c(u)=u^2+1/4,\quad F_e(u)=−\frac{1} {4}u^4+\frac{3} {2}u^2.$$
How were these terms chosen? Just making different combinations of terms until I hit the one where both terms are convex and also their derivatives are linear/nonlinear? What about the contractive/expansive part? Or is there a method?

Comment: Where did you find the example you've given?

Comment: Hi! @KyleKanos in this article: Convex Splitting Method for the Calculation of Transition States of Energy Functional, 
Shuting Gu, Xiang Zhou, https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1610.07153 - example is on page 9

Comment: For those that are voting to close this question, please keep in mind that [computational physics questions **are** on topic on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5603/25301). Sending this question to [math.se] makes no sense to me.

Comment: I suspect some of it will be due to experience, but there may be more to it that I don't see in the paper you linked--other references I've looked at briefly the last few minutes provide the same splitting, so this might also be specific for the Cahn-Hilliard equation & how it applies to other types of equations might rely on a guess-and-check method. I don't have experience in this particular area, so I will leave it to someone more knowledgeable to address it more adeptly.

Comment: @KyleKanos thank you for taking a look at the paper and other references and giving me your opinion on the matter. I'll continue for now with trying out different combinations and just seeing what works.